# Eclipse is not starting

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded **Eclipse indigo 64bit** tar file and extracted it, for my **Ubuntu 12.04**, I have **JDK 1.7** installed in my system, when I am doing:

```
java -Version
bash: /home/rd00/Development/jdk1.7.0/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
```

and

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/rd00/Development/jdk1.7.0/bin
```

is showing, but when I am clicking on eclipse it is not starting, I have given my JDK path in `eclipse.ini` also , but no use,  need help .

Srikanth

Comment: do you get any output when you run `eclipse` from terminal. If yes can you provide that in your question please.

Comment: How did you install `java`? It says it cannot execute the `java` binary and its in your home folder, so did you manually extract and install?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't install Java correctly. Follow this [guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) to install Oracle Java on Ubuntu 12.04 or alternatively install openjdk by running:

```
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```